# For geom_line with integer variable, not all x labels and vertical white lines are displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show all the labels on the x-axis in the trendline chart. I tried specifying the labels with `x_scale_continous`, but they are not displayed either. Also, some lines are now displayed in the default palette of ggplot, i.e. whole lines only appear from x = 1.  You can test this with the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = -3:2, y = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+scale_x_continuous(labels=as.character(x),breaks=x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `ggproto` objects like layers, scales and co-ordinates to a ggplot, you are not actually passing your data frame through to them, and there is no non-standard evaluation or data masking going on.

This means that although in some ways the syntax feels similar to sequential piped functions that you might use in `dplyr`, you do not have unqualified access to the columns in your data frame inside functions like `scale_x_continuous`. You therefore have to specify `df$x`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$x)
```

[image]

The fact that your own code doesn't throw an error suggests that you have a global variable called `x` that is being used inside `scale_x_continuous` instead.